# Can you please clarify the logic behind "one-hot encoding the labels to use MSE" in a Classification Problem

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Thank you Keras Team for the [very detailed explanation about Train and Evaluate](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate/#custom_losses) but I have a query.

I want to understand the statement,

> We need to one-hot encode the labels to use MSE

and want to understand exactly, how **`One-Hot-Encoding`** and **`MSE`** work together (because **`One-Hot-Encoding`** just creates columns with 0's and a 1), in the code mentioned below in the [Documentation of Keras Train and Evaluate](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate/#custom_losses)

```py
def custom_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))


model = get_uncompiled_model()
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=custom_mean_squared_error)

# We need to one-hot encode the labels to use MSE
y_train_one_hot = tf.one_hot(y_train, depth=10)
model.fit(x_train, y_train_one_hot, batch_size=64, epochs=1)
```

Comment: You can find the explanation [here](https://vigneshgig.medium.com/why-one-hot-encoder-is-important-in-classification-model-782c76604034). Thanks!